# Equivalent of Python's min() with lambda in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby

In Ruby, what would be the equivalent of the Python code below?

```
x = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

min(range(len(x)), key=lambda i: y.index(x[i]))
=> 5
```

Edit: I'm just looking for a direct translation from Python to Ruby, don't bother about the  semantic of the provided example.

Comment: I think this means: the element in `x` with the smallest index in `y`.

Comment: Better to use a helper dict than the repeated calls to `.index` eg. `min(range(len(x)), key=(lambda i, d={k:v for v,k in enumerate(y)}: d.get(x[i])))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating directly...

```
(0...x.length).min_by { |i| y.find_index(x[i]) }
```

Built-in functions that take lambdas in python tend to translate to Ruby methods that take blocks (lambdas defined in-line, essentially).

Edit: A slightly more idiomatic translation could be

```
obj,index = x.each_with_index.min_by { |o,i| y.find_index(o) }
index
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to get the index of the smallest element?

```
x = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4]

x.index(x.min()) # => 5
x.each_with_index.min[1] # => 5
(0...x.size).min_by {|i| x[i] } # => 5
```